# Laravel : Overriding canonical urls for specific url

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to override default canonical url to specific url for specific pages.
The list of urls(from and to) are stored in `canonicals` table in database.
Here is the table migration code.

```
Schema::create('canonicals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('from')->unique();
        $table->string('to');
        ...
    });
```

But I don't know how could they be applied to. Here is the current code.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ URL::current() }}"/>
```

It's just displaying default canonical urls and I want it to be overridden for specific pages.

I have researched to doing this and I don't have idea about it.
I think this could be done by `Middleware` or something else. For `Middleware` it looks like it can only doing with `redirect()`. Sorry for poor knowledge of Laravel.
Also I think this must be involved with `Caching` otherwise it'd make site speed slow. I'm looking for a really correct way for this. That'd be great if someone provides a complete code for doing this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried passing your specific canonical url to the unique pages directly from the controller, with a default canonical url for other pages

Comment: I have taken some research and think find out the solution with View::share() function.

Comment: ok, so its resolved then?

Comment: Yes, it's solved the problem